# Wiremock-Problem while accessing multiple stubs in a single json file with wiremock body transformer jar

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "mappings" (class com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.stubbing.StubMapping), not marked as ignorable (10 known properties: "response", "requiredScenarioState", "priority", "persistent", "id", "postServeActions", "request", "newScenarioState", "uuid", "scenarioName"])

## Command to start wiremock

java -cp "wiremock-body-transformer-1.1.3.jar;wiremock-2.3.1-standalone.jar"  com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner --verbose --extensions com.opentable.extension.BodyTransformer --port 8082

Note: While running wiremock-2.3.1-standalone.jar not facing any issue only problem while accessing wiremock-body-transformer

Comment: Can you provide some more information? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What is happening? Can you post the affected transformer and stubs/mappings? Was this working without the response transformer?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can call wiremock api and post multiple stubs(jsons) in one go.
Try this. [Solution here](https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/987)